# Is the series $\sum(\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{2n}}{e^n})$ absolutely convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The question mentions to use root test.So $\limsup((|a_n|^\frac{1}{n}))=A$.If $A<1$ then the series is convergent.

So $|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}= \frac{(1+1/n)^2}{e}$.How am I to find the $\limsup$ of the sequence, I  put $\lim_{n->\infty}\frac{(1+1/n)}{e}=1/e$, so $A<1$ .Hence the series is convergent. Is this OK?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.